# Make Cortana Skill close Cortana canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, botframework, cortana-skills-kit

is there a possibility to make the Cortana Skill close the Cortana Canvas itself?

I've tried

```
var completeMessage = context.MakeMessage();
completeMessage.Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation;
completeMessage.AsEndOfConversationActivity().Code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully;
await context.PostAsync(completeMessage);
```

but it doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way for developers to close the Cortana canvas.